# When adding a new row to an Antd table, make it the first row visible?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Just started using Ant, have been loving it so far. I have a working ant table and add row button, however when a row is added, it is added at the end of all rows since its ID is incremented from the last ID in the table. I am working with less than a 1,000 items.

Is there common logic or a property I can change to make adding a new row visible at the beginning by default? This way a user can visibly confirm that their actions succeeded.

Some ideas around this are:

- Add a date created field and have it hidden by default, but sort by newest date
- Figure out a way to make the ID column invisible and display the largest ID first..this  not scalable when using GUIDs which I would prefer :(
- Temporarily render the newly added row data in a special container in the table? No idea on how to go about trying this.

Comment: What if you sort it by date (descending) order and add to antd table?. So, what ever you add will come first automatically.

Comment: @Blasanka Yeah, would it possible to hide this date column but have it used and sorted by descending when a new row is added?